Why is there an "Access level changed: Access now read-write" in my chat reply log?
I see on https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/44764/franck-dernoncourt?userId=44764&tab=replies&StartDate=2024-08-01&EndDate=2024-09-01:

Access level changed: Access now read-write


Why is there an "Access level changed: Access now read-write" in my chat reply log? If that pertains to the chatroom  on the left, I don't have write access to it since it is frozen.

On August 17th, a moderator moved a bunch of messages to the chatroom in your screenshot. When a moderator moves comments to chat, it grants all participants "Explicit write access" in order to allow users who cannot ordinarily use chat (as they may not have enough reputation for the Talk in chat privilege) the ability to speak there. You can observe that you have this access by looking at the Access tab when looking at the room's info.
August 17th is within the boundaries of your "Replies" query, which is showing notifications from between August 1st and September 1st.
To my knowledge, this access level change doesn't give you a ping, but it strangely does appear in your "replies" tab. I've got one in my replies as well:


What does “Not an Edited Room Name” mean?

@TymaGaidash Nothing, I just changed the name of the room here for privacy reasons for the purposes of screenshotting it. That room is a private room, so I'd consider its existence secret.
